# Reshape DatePicker

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, calendar

I have found a solution only to display the calendar without the input field.
But unfortunately, the current calendar is not what I wanted.

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

However, I want to make the calendar slightly different.Is it possible by code to reshape the calendar so? The new calendar would not be as wide as the old calendar (old calendar = first photo).

I would be glad if you could give me tips on how to reshape the calendar.

[image]

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(new DatePicker(LocalDate.now()));
        Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();

        root.setCenter(popupContent);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is too broad. The shortest answer is to write your own custom control from scratch. The indirect answer is to find out all sub-components in a `DatePicker` and try your best to tweak the appearance through CSS. Seriously, you are not going to get a complete solution either way because it's too complex. If this is easy, then you wouldn't find 3rd-party API vendors selling those cool `DatePicker` with a premium.

Comment: Why won't you use [ControlsFX extras](http://jfxtras.org/)? It may be the closest thing besides creating your own node.